# BlogCards Component doesn't show up on vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a web app which shows the blog posts in a grid. But the BlogCards component in the Home.vue just outputs nothing, whereas it should output the blogs in a grid format. All the datas are stored in firebase. If I go to /blogs, I can see the blogs in grid format, but it doesn't work on the Home.vue. It also spits out the **Vue Warn: property or method "blogPostsCards" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.**

I took this code from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISv22NNL-aE) at 5:31:05 minute mark.

Any solution to this problem.

Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <BlogPost :post="post" v-for="(post, index) in blogPostsFeed" :key="index" />
    <div class="blog-card-wrap">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>View more recent blogs</h3>
        <div class="blog-cards">
          <BlogCards :post="post" v-for="(post, index) in blogPostsCard" :key="index" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import BlogPost from '../components/BlogPost.vue'
import BlogCards from '../components/BlogCards.vue'

export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    BlogPost,
    BlogCards,
    Arrow
  },
  computed : {
    blogPostsCards() {
      return this.$store.getters.blogPostsCards;
    },
    blogPostsFeed() {
      return this.$store.getters.blogPostsFeed;
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

BlogCards.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="blog-card">
        <img :src="post.blogCoverPhoto" alt="">
        <div class="info">
            <h4>{{ post.blogTitle }}</h4>
            <h6>Posted on: {{ new Date(post.blogDate).toLocaleString('en-us', {dateStyle: "long"})}}</h6>
            <router-link class="link" to="#" >
                View Post <Arrow class="arrow" />
            </router-link>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "blogCard",
    props: ["post"],
    computed: {
        editPost() {
            return this.$store.state.editPost
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

And getter function in store/index.js

```
getters:{
    blogPostsFeed(state){
      return state.blogPosts.slice(0,2);
    },
    blogPostsCards(state) {
      return state.blogPosts.slice(2,6);
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<BlogCards :post="post" v-for="(post, index) in blogPostsCard" :key="index" />
```

In your Home.vue >> change **blogPostsCard** to *blogPostsCards* because you use *blogPostsCards* in your computed so it gives you that error.

Comment: OMG thank you so much. I don't know why I didn't see that.